# draw and rotate multi image on canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas, rotation, drawimage

I want to draw four images on canvas as below.

However, I want to use only one image, not four.

(use only img0, not use img90/img180/img270)

In other words, I want to draw four images with different rotation directions with one image(img0) on canvas.

Is that possible?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')

var img0 = new Image()
img0.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vxxK.png'
img0.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img0, 0, 0)
}, false);

var img90 = new Image()
img90.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EgLn.png'
img90.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img90, 20, 0)
}, false);

var img180 = new Image()
img180.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us9fa.png'
img180.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img180, 40, 0)
}, false);

var img270 = new Image()
img270.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO9f9.png"
img270.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img270, 60, 0)
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

[sample image degree 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vxxK.png)

[sample image degree 90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EgLn.png)

[sample image degree 180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us9fa.png)

[sample image degree 270](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO9f9.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can use the `ctx.rotate("degrees" * Math.PI / 180);` function. Replace the `"degrees"` with the amount you'd like to rotate the image for.